# Do numerical Conditions stack?

Tags: conditions, stacking, pathfinder-2e

2e introduced quite a lot of new rules, one being [conditions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx). I didn't find any quote there and it left me wondering: Does drained (and other conditions) stack?

Example: One poison says:

> Stage 1 1d6 poison damage and drained 1 (1 hour); Stage 2 2d6 poison damage and drained 2 (1 hour); Stage 3 3d6 poison damage and drained 2 (1 hour)

If a creature fails Saves such that they are affected by stage 1, then 2, then 3, do you have 5 drained or only 2?

Comment: I made some fairly significant edits, but I believe I kept the intent of your question and broadened it to help draw attention and prevent redundant (no pun intended) questions. If you feel like I changed your message, feel free to roll it back or re-edit it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Conditions with Different Values Don't Accumulate

This is addressed in the [redundant conditions with values](http://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=774) sidebar on pg.623.

> Conditions with different values are considered different conditions. If you’re affected by a condition with a value multiple times, you apply only the highest value, although you might have to track both durations if one has a lower value but lasts longer

So in a hypothetical case where you already have Drained 1, then get hit with Drained 2, you only "feel" Drained 2.

Comment: hmmm could it be that it was part of an errata? (618 has no sidebar for me but not using any erratas so far nor did I looked thhrough them)

Comment: @ThomasE. Found it. Edited with the real page number.